# find element and set the value

Tags: jquery

i have a div element with id `hover-1`, within the div i have a hidden form element having class name `text_page_title` in the hierarchy.
i got the parent div element id dyanamically in a variable, now i want to find the hidden element having class name `text_page_title` and set its value to 'foo'

structure is like:

```
<div id="hover-1">
<input type="hidden" class="text_page_title">
</div>
<div id="hover-2">
<input type="hidden" class="text_page_title">
</div>
```

I m trying to do it like:

```
$($parentId).find('input.text_page_title').val('foo');
```

but it doesnt work, m i missing something?

Comment: That should work. My guess is that you have the `id` in `$parentId`, but don't have the `#`, so try `$("#" + $parentId)`.

Comment: `$("#" + $parentId).children(".text_page_title").attr("value", "foo");`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works:

```
$("#hover-1").find('input.text_page_title').val('foo'); // or $("#hover-2")
```

If you want your parent id in a variable:

```
var parentId = $("#hover-1"); // or $("#hover-2");
parentId.find('input.text_page_title').val('foo');
```

[working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pMAhK/)

Comment: .attr('value', 'foo'); is useless as it is an input - we can use val()

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `parentId` is the variable name containing the id string ("hover-1"), you should rewrite your quesry like this:

```
$('#'+parentId).find('input.text_page_title').val('foo');
```

Answer (score 1):

If $parentId is the parent Id:

```
$('#'+$parentId).find('input.text_page_title:hidden').val('foo');
```

You will be sure to get only hidden input

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
 $("#hover-1").find(".text_page_title").val('foo');
```